# How to compile Android's mdnsresponder

Tags: android, compilation

I want to change the hostname that my Android phone broadcasts from `Android`. From [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/242004/355488), I found out that I have to edit the source code of `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mdnsresponder`. I did, now how do I compile it? `make` both in the root and in `mDNSPosix` does not work.

EDIT: I tried `soong_build -b test -l Android.bp -o Android.ninja Android.bp` but it fails with `panic: Found two Blueprint files in directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it, but it's a bit involved (and I may be missing a few steps):

All steps can be run on anywhere the Android NDK is supported

1. Clone `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mdnsresponder`
2. `cd` into it.
3. `mkdir include` and download `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libcutils` into it.
4. Edit `mDNSPosix/mDNSPosix.c`

```
#ifndef __ANDROID__
       gethostname((char *)(&namelabel->c[1]), MAX_DOMAIN_LABEL);
   #else
       // use an appropriate default label rather than the linux default of 'localhost'
       strncpy(&namelabel->c[1], "Android", MAX_DOMAIN_LABEL);
```

to

```
#ifndef __ANDROID__
    gethostname((char *)(&namelabel->c[1]), MAX_DOMAIN_LABEL);
#else
    const char* hostname = getenv("HOSTNAME");
    // use an appropriate default label rather than the linux default of 'localhost'
    strncpy(&namelabel->c[1], hostname, MAX_DOMAIN_LABEL);
```

5. Edit `mDNSPosix/PosixDaemon.c` and remove

```
if (mStatus_NoError == err)
        {
        const struct passwd *pw = getpwnam(MDNS_USERNAME);
        if (pw != NULL)
            setuid(pw->pw_uid);
        else
            LogMsg("WARNING: mdnsd continuing as root because user \"%s\" does not exist", MDNS_USERNAME);
        }
```

6. Download the Android NDK [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) and unpack it. The location will be known as `$NDK`.
7. Copy `/system/lib64/libcutils.so` to `$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/31/libcutils.so`
8. Then, execute this:

```
$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang-12 --target=aarch64-linux-android31 -O2  -g  -fno-strict-aliasing  -fwrapv  -D_GNU_SOURCE  -DHAVE_IPV6  -DNOT_HAVE_SA_LEN  -DPLATFORM_NO_RLIMIT  -DMDNS_DEBUGMSGS=0  -DMDNS_UDS_SERVERPATH='"/dev/socket/mdnsd"' -DMDNS_USERNAME='"mdnsr"'  -W  -Wall  -Wextra  -Wno-address-of-packed-member  -Wno-array-bounds  -Wno-pointer-sign  -Wno-unused  -Wno-unused-const-variable  -Wno-unused-parameter  -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DTARGET_OS_LINUX -DHAVE_LINUX -DUSES_NETLINK -Werror -I./mDNSCore        -I./mDNSPosix        -I./mDNSShared mDNSCore/DNSCommon.c        -I./include -DMDNS_VERSIONSTR_NODTS=1 -lcutils mDNSCore/DNSDigest.c        -llog mDNSCore/mDNS.c        mDNSCore/uDNS.c        mDNSPosix/mDNSPosix.c        mDNSPosix/mDNSUNP.c        mDNSPosix/PosixDaemon.c        mDNSShared/dnssd_ipc.c        mDNSShared/GenLinkedList.c        mDNSShared/mDNSDebug.c        mDNSShared/PlatformCommon.c        mDNSShared/uds_daemon.c
```

9. The `mdnsd` is at `./a.out`
10. Execute with `HOSTNAME=<whatever you want> ./a.out`